# Python. Append CSV files in a folder into one big file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am a little confused with a Pandas library and would really appreciate your help.

The task is to combine all *.csv files in a folder into one big file.
CSV files don't have a header, so I just want to append all of them and add a header in the end.

Here is the code I use.
The final file is "ALBERTA GENERAL", in the beginning I delete the old one before creating an updated version.

```
os.chdir(dataFolder)
with io.open("ALBERTA GENERAL.csv", "w+", encoding='utf8') as f:
os.remove("ALBERTA GENERAL.csv")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=False) for f in all_filenames], axis=0, ignore_index = True)
print(combined_csv)

with io.open('ALBERTA GENERAL.csv', "w+", encoding='utf8') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames=["Brand, Name, Strain, Genre, Product type, Date"],delimiter=";")
    writer.writeheader()

    combined_csv.to_csv(outcsv, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

But I get a confusing result that I don't know how to fix.
The final file doesn't append intermediate files one below another, but it adds columns for the next file. I tried to add the same headers to the intermediate files but it did not help.

Other than that the header is not split by columns and is recognized as one line.

Can anyone help me to fix my code, please?

Here is [the link to the files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W7kr0Fu3BifSrGQM8lSuy4H-2y_zYhNP)

Comment: Your files are irregular. Do you have control over their output?

Comment: Hi @mechanical_meat, do you mean ";" signs? Those are examples of my files. The full file contains text data with many commas, that's why I need to use ";" as a separator.

Comment: I see that you're using `;` as a field separator, that's ok. But `ALBERTA GENERAL.csv` is the most problematic file. It has some `;` in the beginning and end of lines.

Comment: Yes, I can change output for any of those files, they are created by me before they go to the combining stage. This ALBERTA_GENERAL file is created automatically based on the other 2, and it acts really strange. the first line after the header is created from the 1st line of both files, then starting from the second line it shows only the first file. And only when the 1st file is over it starts showing the second file starting from the next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fix the irregularities of the first file:

```
with open('ALBERTA GENERAL.csv','r') as f_in, open('ALBERTA GENERAL_fixed.csv','w') as f_out: 
    for line in f_in: 
        line = line.replace(',',';') 
        line = line.strip().rstrip(';') 
        line = line.strip().lstrip(';') 
        f_out.write(line + '\n') 

os.remove('ALBERTA_GENERAL.csv')
```

We will import the first file separately because it has different requirements than the others:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('ALBERTA GENERAL_fixed.csv',header=0,sep=';')
```

We can then do the other two:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('file_ALBERTA_05.14.2020.csv',header=None,sep=';')
df3 = pd.read_csv('file_ALBERTA_05.18.2020.csv',header=None,sep=';')

df2.columns = df1.columns
df3.columns = df1.columns
```

Final steps:

```
combined = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
combined.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```